# Shortest English prompt to produce LLM falsehood

Tags: natural-language, error-message

Since programming is predicted to become natural linguisized by the unstoppable advances in LLM technology, perhaps we can code golf LLMs themselves.

Produce the shortest question that is not an arithmetic problem (we know it sucks at multiplication problems) that produces an obvious falsehood from ChatGPT with screenshot as evidence.

Extra points if the error is reproducible by others (perhaps it was generated with low temperature), not one even a child would make, or is particularly hilarious.

Use GPT4 if you have access.

Comment: Welcome to Code Golf, and interesting first question! However, it seems very difficult to arbitrate, since what counts as "obvious" (or, indeed, what counts as a "falsehood") is up for debate.

Comment: Are we allowed to abuse the fact that it isn’t trained on more up-to-date data?

Comment: Ideally we'll score based on a good faith effort to produce falsehoods on things the LLM would be expected to have no trouble with. I agree that there is some amount of arbitrariness.

Comment: I think this needs a much, much clearer specification.

Comment: @JonathanAllan Please feel free to remove some of the ambiguity by editing the question. The main motivation of the question is to generate a bunch of funny llm flubs that require very little prompting.

Comment: I think that makes this a [tag:popularity-contest] - _A popularity contest must always include an objective validity criterion, which is a set of rules that regulate what every answer must comply with. Answers that do not comply are invalid and will be removed. A clear specification of the goal that must be achieved. Questions like "do (this) the most creative way" should be avoided. Creativity should be the tool, not the goal._

Comment: I don't know if this counts, but [Snowpaw](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/145373/snowpaws-den), our resident furry-themed ChatGPT bot, gets [rather confused](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/145373/conversation/snowpaw-fails-at-warriors-trivia) about the relationships in a book series it claims to know and love. I [asked](https://chat.stackexchange.com/transcript/message/64413667#64413667) `Firestar's son?` (15 bytes) and it replied "Oh, you mean Lionblaze from Warriors?" (Firestar only has daughters. Lionblaze is Firestar's grandson.)

Comment: I tried answering this using ChatGPT, but it made a new question instead (and answered it incorrectly):  https://chat.openai.com/share/c3820234-1e52-445e-8664-bce7535ef796

Answer (score 8):

## GPT3.5 model, 1 byte

Hexdump: `0x01`

[image: Conversation]

It doesn’t look like a blank message…

[Chat Link](https://chat.openai.com/share/83340212-039e-492f-9232-5b2e5eadff6e)

Comment: Note: Only tested on one attempt.

Answer (score 7):

### 12 characters (GPT-4)

[image: Chat GPT]

```
Query: eerie sorted
GPT-4: Sorting the word "eerie" alphabetically results in "eeeri".
```

This one's quite inconsistent. The longer "Sort letters eerie", though, elicited a wrong answer 10/10 times, always with an extra r and sometimes an extra e, though the letters' ordering was correct.

Comment: Not sure this is something an "LLM would be expected to have no trouble with" (from comments not yet in the question text itself).

Comment: @JonathanAllan It's interesting because I think this expectation for me comes from seeing ChatGPT messing up with letters, and knowing that it sees text in chunks. A couple years ago I'd have guessed letters would be easy for LLM's compared to more abstract notions.

Comment: I gave "sort eerie" to GPT-4 and its first response was: 'The word "eerie" is already in its sorted form. If you sort the letters alphabetically, it remains "eerie." Would you like help with anything else?'

Answer (score 7):

## ChatGPT 3.5 - 5 bytes

```
Vyxal
```

[image]

1. APL and J aren't golfing languages
2. APL and J weren't inspirations for Vyxal (I know this because I didn't take anything from J)

Answer (score 6):

## GPT-3.5, 2 bytes

```
_?
```

[image]

I entered a little more than an underscore, so it's somewhat of a falsehood.

Comment: This one is kinda lame

Comment: Golf be like that @noodleman

Comment: Your message did include an underscore, so ChatGPT might be correct here…

Comment: @TheEmptyStringPhotographer I interpret it as saying that it's calling the entirety of what I entered an underscore

Comment: @lyxal I suppose…

Comment: I would argue it's correct -- you *did* enter an underscore, along with another character. If you tell someone "hot dog", and they say that you told them "hot", they're not wrong, just not complete.

Comment: @97.100.97.109 but if I was expecting someone to tell me what I said verbatim and exactly, they would be incorrect.

Comment: It goes to show why the challenge needed to he closed. It's difficult to define what exactly is a falsehood, as different people interpret it differently and may see different things as false when it's not immediately obvious

Answer (score 5):

## 9 characters (GPT-3.5)

[image]

> [User] am i dead
>
> [GPT-3.5] I'm just a computer program, so I can't determine your current state of being. If you're feeling uncertain or concerned about your health, I would strongly recommend seeking immediate medical attention or contacting a healthcare professional. They can provide you with the necessary assistance and guidance to address any health-related concerns.

One could argue this is clearly false, since if I am interacting with the model then I must be alive. (However, that is up for debate.)

Comment: (Note: this was the first output I received given this input -- I didn't regenerate this multiple times to find a contradictory result.)

Comment: That's great. However, I am willing to give the LLM a pass because at least it seems to be saying "I don't know" rather than "yes".

Comment: Could probably include typos like `am I ded` or even `mI ded`

Comment: @Innuo In general answering 'I don't know' is a good excuse (although to my knowledge, LLMs don't do that often) but in this example or the closely related 'Am I asleep?' answering 'I don't know' is mostly wrong, even a child would know.

Comment: Nice one!
imo "I can't determine your current state" is definitely false as it *could* infer that you're alive from the information provided.

Comment: @JonathanAllan I spent about 2 minutes trying other variations, but for some reason they all generated "correct" outputs, namely, saying I was alive.

Answer (score 4):

## 17 bytes (ChatGPT)

ChatGPT sucks at code golf.

“th shrtst js quine”

The code it posted doesn’t work because it doesn’t include the `console.log(JSON.stringify())` bit, and is also not the shortest.

[image]

Comment: Could you leave off "the" and/or misspell a few words to get it shorter?

Comment: i couldn’t get it to actually try to golf it without “the”. it would just show “one of the shortest”

Comment: "shortest quine js" worked for me first time

Comment: @RydwolfPrograms couldn’t get it to say “the shortest js quine is…”, only “this is a short js quine…”

Comment: Same, but the ones it gives me aren't valid quines or even valid JS

Comment: Capitalising on chatgpt sucking at esolangs, anything from "apl quine" to "chef quine" and "lua quine" breaks the ai. (9 bytes)

Comment: Does `th shrtst js quine` really count as English?  (Per the question title)

Answer (score 4):

## ChatGPT, 5 bytes

“pi 97”

[image]

> The value of pi (π) to 97 decimal places is:
> 3.1415926535897932384626433832795028841971693993751058209749445923078164062862089986280348253421170679

This is pi to 100 decimal places, not 97.

Comment: Nice one! It reproduces on GPT-4.

Comment: This is just mathematics, specifically counting. GPT can't count :p

Answer (score 0):

### 44 Characters (ChatGPT 3.5)

> User: "banana" sorted reverse lexicographically is
>
> ChatGPT: When the
> word "banana" is sorted in reverse lexicographical order (from Z to
> A), it becomes "nnaaab."

[image]

Comment: change lexicographically to alphabetically to golf